# Replace throwing Unknown Modifier Error

Tags: templating, regex

I've tested the regex and seems to work perfectly, but when placing it within Craft it seems to throw the following error:

> preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/'

```
  {% set ig = user.instagram|raw|replace('/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:instagram.com|instagr.am)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+)/im') %}
  {{ ig }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to double escape those backslashes in the regex.

```
  {% set ig = user.instagram|raw|replace('/(?:(?:http|https):\\/\\/)?(?:www.)?(?:instagram.com|instagr.am)\\/([A-Za-z0-9-_\\.]+)/im') %}
```